# How to send big files from URL to Telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have some big size files (in `MP4` and `Zip` formats) and I want to send them to my chat by Telegram bot, I used the code below:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot[[app:token]]/sendDocument?chat_id=24523586&document='.$fileAddress);
```

But it just can send files with small sizes, less than 50MB! But I know there is no file size limitation for documents which are sending by `file_id`. You can see [this page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)
Now how can I make `file_id` for my files? My files are uploaded on my server and I am using PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Telegram bot API can only send files less than 20 MB by `url` param, you should lookup [Sending Files](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) section.

If you want to send 20-50 MB files, you should download and re-upload to Telegram bot API server.
You can refer this simple code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot131210513:AXXXXXX/sendDocument?caption=Hello+World&chat_id=24523586',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    ],
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'document' => curl_file_create('/etc/hosts', 'plain/text', 'Hosts-file.txt')
    ]
]);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3):

**2021 Update:** [Telegram now provides a self hostable Telegram Bot API](https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api) which can upload 1.5GB.

You can install [pwrtelegram](https://github.com/pwrtelegram/pwrtelegram) on your server. Then simply switch the API URL and you will be able to upload up to 1.5 GB of files with your bot. That is the only possible way. Check out the link for more information.

Also, you **cannot** pass in any random `file_id`, as Telegram will not send it. You can only pass in a file_id which has been uploaded by your bot previously. To bypass the limit, use the method, above. It works very well.

Comment: thanks for helping :) is there any simple php source to send files for PWRTelegram?

Comment: Actually just switch the APi url to api.pwrtelegram.xyz and you are good to go

Comment: sorry, i switch the APi url to api.pwrtelegram.xyz but it doesnt work !