# Send Video to Telegram via bot using multipart/form-data

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to Send a video to Telegram with bot using multipart/form-data
I use below codes, It works for files smaller than 20MB but doesn't work for files larger than 20MB but Telegram API reference says:

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

```
$chatId=1111111;
$video=urlencode("http://video/mp4");
$botToken = "mytoken";
$webSite = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;
$url = $webSite. "/sendVideo"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "chat_id=$chatId&video=$video");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($output); // show output
```

The result that I get in the browser is:

```
 "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}"
```

I've tried for two different videos in the same host it works for the file that is smaller than 20MB but doesn't work for another one which is 35 MB.

Comment: do you get any error on your log file ?

Comment: Result in browser is :
 "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}"

Comment: if you try the same code with a file < 20MB . what message you have on the browser ?

Comment: "{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":46,"from": ....

Comment: Telegram bot API can only send files less than 20 MB by url param, you should lookup Sending Files section.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

Comment: see the Question Here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256917/how-to-send-big-files-from-url-to-telegram-bot

Comment: do you find you solution in this question ?